# Identifying number of facilities within service area in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, service-area

I am trying to identify the facilities within a Service Area. I have 100 points (facilities) where I created Service Area polygons of 5 km each. Now I need to know how many of these 100 facilities are within these Service Areas. In short, for service area of facility 1, what other facilities are within this area etc? The result needs to be a image of a service area with a table of all other facilities within this area.

I now do an intersect between the facilities and service areas which results in a point dataset of facilities with a column in which service area they fall in, but unfortunatly this also gives back all facilities that fall within their own service area. I have to delete the intersect of facility 1 with its own service area. I have a feeling that there might be an easier way to do this.

Comment: But I need the attribute data also. So for each service area I need to know which facilities are within the area, and what the names of each facility are

Comment: Use Spatial Join tool http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm

Comment: A spatial join also joins a facility to its own service area, something I don't want.

Comment: So you want to create a map for each facility? With data driven pages?

Comment: Yes, and for each service area a table with all facilities within it, except the facility of the service area itself